# Calculate difference between 2 dates

Tags: mysql, sql, datediff

I have been asked to make a Power BI report where it shows some details about organization service desk.
I've made it easily but, there is one thing there I couldn't figure out: they asked me to show the average time that every support analyst take to resolve the tickets. **The problem is: I have to calculate the avg time only between 8:00 AM and 6:00 PM in avery day. it means that a day have only 10 hours. I tried to do this in SQL (MySQL) but nothing came out.**

Sorry if it is a stupid question, I'm still learning SQL and Power BI.

I tried:

```sql
CASE WHEN EXTRACT(HOUR FROM tick.CREATED) >= 8 AND
EXTRACT(HOUR FROM tick.TIME_CLOSED) <= 18 AND
weekday(tick.CREATED) not in (6,7) THEN
TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,tick.CREATED,tick.TIME_CLOSED) END
```

But I don't know a way to skip the hours out of this range and continue counting the hours in the next day.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This community won't be able to do much to help you until you've shown your work. Please include the relevant code you're using (e.g. the SQL statement that you already constructed). Please also include what you've tried.

Comment: Itried:  CASE WHEN EXTRACT(HOUR FROM tick.CREATED) >= 8 AND EXTRACT(HOUR FROM tick.TIME_CLOSED) <= 18 AND weekday(tick.CREATED) not in (6,7) THEN
 TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,tick.CREATED,tick.TIME_CLOSED)
END . But I don't know a way to skip the hours out of this range and continue counting the hours in the next day.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, please change column names and maybe add a group by if you needed by each day

```
SELECT AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,`from`,`to`))
FROM (
    SELECT `to`  
        ,CASE 
            -- if saturday then start date will be next monday first hour
            WHEN weekday(`from`) = 6 then CONCAT(DATE(DATE_ADD(`from`, INTERVAL 2 DAY)),' 08:00:00') 
            -- if sunday then start date will be next monday first hour
            WHEN weekday(`from`) = 7 then CONCAT(DATE(DATE_ADD(`from`, INTERVAL 1 DAY)),' 08:00:00') 
            -- if created outside business time then next day first hour
            WHEN `from` between CONCAT(DATE(`from`),' 18:00:00') and CONCAT(DATE(DATE_ADD(`from`, INTERVAL 1 DAY)),' 08:00:00') then CONCAT(DATE(DATE_ADD(`from`, INTERVAL 1 DAY)),' 08:00:00')
            ELSE `from`
        END `from`
    FROM ticket
    WHERE `from` is not null
        AND `to` is not null
) t
WHERE DATE(`from`) = DATE (`to`); -- if you want only ticket closed same day, its optional
```